# Sedan car door modified - inspection issues

Tags: door, body-work, inspection

I am interested in buying a car where the seller modified the car door into Lamborghini-like butterfly doors.

Will there be safety issues, so that the mod will not pass state inspection?

Let's presume a general spread of TX, CA, FL, MA, NY inspections.

Comment: Your best bet is to go and ask someone who does the inspections where you live. I have tried unsuccessfully in finding your answer. Doesn't mean it doesn't exist, but you know the deal. Most Lambo hinge manufacturers state, "*For recreational or off-road use only*" so it isn't looking good! Though I wonder how Lamborghini's themselves get registered if they are no legal?

Answer (score 2):

I would assume not.

Up here in Canada, our vehicle inspection is pretty lax, but Lambo-doors introduce a pretty big safety issue, and they are not allowed on the road. I have yet to see a kit that deals with the problem of a car that has been flipped.

I believe that Lambo's have windshields that can be broken outwards in case of a rollover. Mercedes' Gullwings have exploding bolts. This is most of the reason why these kits are rejected from safeties. I'm sure that you can probably argue to get it passed if you work out this problem, and any other problem they can present to you.

Answer (score 2):

west coast customs install gullwings regularly but laws from state to state vary.For
your own peace of mind (and safety) I would have an engineer inspect and certify.Last
thing you want is an unroadworthy tag